# Unable to run web application with maven in netbeans?

Tags: maven, netbeans

I am getting this error in the Netbeans output console.

> "D:\apache-maven-3.3.9\bin\mvn.bat"' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Comment: The command `mvn` runs Maven, which is a build tool.  Are you trying to build your project or launch it?

Comment: Install Maven, it's nice version. Use it manually or with your netbeans what ever you prefer i don't know what is the question about.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you've not set the environment variables properly. you can set it from the system properties (on a windows pc) 
variable name : M2_HOME and
variable value : D:\apache-maven-3.3.9 (location where maven is installed)

Answer (score 0):

To execute the mvn command you should go to the mvn bin folder if you are not set the environment path to maven home.
after set the maven home path you can access wherever you want.

Here easy guild to setup maven 
https://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-install-maven-in-windows/